# Handling trailing newlines with Python str.splitlines()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm implementing text drawing on an image, and am trying to handle newlines by implementing a "text cursor" that advances appropriately.

I have a solution for handling trailing newlines, but it's ugly and un-Pythonic. What would be the Pythonic way?

Here's what I'm doing now (simplified code for example purposes):

```
# string may contain zero or more newlines, may or may not terminate in a newline

def text(string):

    for line in string.splitlines():

        global x_cursor, y_cursor           # pixel location of cursor in image

        x_size_of_text = draw_one_line_of_text(line)
        old_x_cursor = x_cursor

        x_cursor = 0
        y_cursor += 20                      # lines are 20 pixels high

    if string[-1] != '\n':                  # if no trailing newline, undo final newline

        x_cursor = old_x_cursor + x_size_of_text
        y_cursor -= 20
```

I do a newline after every line returned by string.splitline(), and then *undo* the newline if the original string didn't terminate in a newline.

This works, but it's ugly. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks; fixed. (It was an artifact from simplifying the code for the question.)

Comment: it often happens when simplifying :) the best way is to create a [mcve] that does what you describe (by testing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tell `splitlines` to keep the end of lines when splitting (by passing `True` as optional argument).

Then, on each line, don't go to the next line if there is no newline (you have to strip `line` when displaying.

for line in string.splitlines(True):

```
    global x_cursor, y_cursor           # pixel location of cursor in image

    x_size_of_text = draw_one_line_of_text(line.rstrip())
    old_x_cursor = x_cursor
    if line.endswith("\n"):
       x_cursor = 0
       y_cursor += 20                      # lines are 20 pixels high
```

That avoids the final test, but introduces a lot of extra testing & complexity, just to handle the last case. I see no problem sticking to your solution (it's ugly but fast - *better ask for forgiveness than for permission*).

One objection, instead of:

```
if string[-1] != '\n':  # if string is empty: Index out of range exception
```

I'd do:

```
if string and not string.endswith("\n"):
```

If the string is empty your test would crash your program. Besides, there would be nothing to correct so test for empty string first.

Comment: Very helpful. (My real code has try...execpt IndexError to catch empty strings. I thought it was distracting from the question, so left it out.)